# Super script within axis label using ggplot2 or ggpubr

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels, ggpubr

I have been trying to raise the 2 in m^2 and get mu to look like the special character, but cant seem to figure it out. I've tried this and many others including the unicode, adding quotes isolating whats not supposed to be raised. Any help would be great. Thank you!

Here is my code:

```
ggboxplot(Photo_Mass_2021, x = "Species", y = "Pn_N", title= "Net Photosynthesis by Species", ylab= expression(paste("Net Photosynthesis ((mumol/m^2*/s)/ mass (g))")), color = "Species", add = "jitter", legend = "none") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(Photo_Mass_2021$Pn_N), linetype = 2)+
  stat_compare_means(method = "anova", label.y = 170)+ stat_compare_means(label = "p.signif", method = "t.test",ref.group = ".all.")
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Jenna Welcome to GitHub! The code you provided is more than enough for the question, but as I show in my answer, even simpler code could have been used. (Of course, it is not that obvious that one can create a ggplot without plotting any data.)

Comment: Use `mu*mol`. … problem solved. Read `?plotmath`. The “mu” will be interpreted as lowercase Greek letter and the “mol” as ordinary alphabetic character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `expression()` for labels check `help(plotmath)` and `example(plotmath)` for the syntax. It takes time to get used to this syntax, but two key things to remember are that `*` can be used to join things without inserting space and `~` adds a space (or rather a narrow space). You can protect parts of the text with quotation marks so that it is not interpreted as an expression. Subcripts are indicated by `[ ]` and superscripts by `^`. I changed your label following the rule that quantities and units should not be mixed. (Some people disagree about this.)  My answer uses the minimum of code necessary to answer your question. (This is also the recommended approach for questions.)

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
labs(y = expression("Net Photosynthesis per mass "*(mu*mol~m^{-2}~s^{-1}~g^{-1})))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: The only material that needs to be quoted is that which would otherwise have special meaning in the plotmath system or is a reserved word in R. Reserved words include “if”, “else”, “for” and a few others.

Answer (score 0):

I was confronted by this problem and the only way is to combine `ggplot2` with `ggpubr` like this modification: Remove ylab from the ggpubr code and add a ggplot labs then write the expression considering *before the greek letter and ~ after

```
ggboxplot(Photo_Mass_2021, x = "Species", y = "Pn_N", title= "Net Photosynthesis by Species", 
color = "Species", add = "jitter", legend = "none") +   
      geom_hline(yintercept = mean(Photo_Mass_2021$Pn_N), linetype = 2) + 
         stat_compare_means(method = "anova", label.y = 170) + 
stat_compare_means(label = "p.signif", method = "t.test",ref.group = ".all.")+
labs(y=expression("Net Photosynthesis ((mumol/m^2*/s)/ mass (g))"))
```

Comment: "Net Photosynthesis"*mu~mol/m^2*/s)/ mass (g)