# Exponent on xlabs in ggscatter

Tags: r, ggplot2, expression, axis-labels

I am trying to add an exponent to my x axis labels but apparently the `expression()` is not used in `ggscatter`

```
ggscatter(database, x ="x" , y = "y",
          add = "reg.line",conf.int = TRUE, 
          xlab=expression(m.g^-1),ylab="yaxis")
```

but I get a `lifecycle::deprecate_soft()` error
is there a way to add exponents to `xlab=` or is there any other way around it

I search similar questions but none solved my problem

Comment: leave the `xlab` out of the `ggscatter` call and add it afterwards using standard ggplot2 syntax - see this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/75530087/16730940

Comment: Thanks that was so obvious. That solves my problem